# Split Table of Contents but not Summary

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, shorttoc

I use `\shorttoc` to have a short table of contents at the beginning and `\tableofcontents` for a complete table of contents at the end.

I need to split the complete table of contents BUT NOT the shorter one. Hopefully the minimal example below will explain this and why.

Now if I use

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\pagebreak}
```

at the point I want the pagebreak to occur, then it will affect (in a rather ugly way) the short table of contents as well.

Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,b5paper]{book}

\usepackage[tight]{shorttoc}

\begin{document}

\shorttoc{\centerline{\large{SOMMAIRE}}}{0}

\chapter{Chapter} \section{Section} \section{Another section} \section{Yet another section}
\chapter{Chapter} \section{Section} \section{Another section} \section{Yet another section}
\chapter{Chapter} \section{Section} \section{Another section} \section{Yet another section}
\chapter{Chapter} \section{Section} \section{Another section} \section{Yet another section}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\pagebreak}
\chapter{Chapter} \section{Section} \section{Another section} \section{Yet another section}
\chapter{Last Chapter} 


\tableofcontents


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Why do you want to split the TOC? If it's because the document for some natural major document divisions and if you're using `book` or equivalent, howsabout introducing `\part's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\pagebreak}
```

use

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\tocbreak}
```

Wherever you want to add the short table of contents, you write:

```
\let\tocbreak=\relax
\shorttoc{\centerline{\large{SOMMAIRE}}}{0}
```

And wherever you want to add the long table of contents, you write:

```
\let\tocbreak=\pagebreak
\tableofcontents
```

So, your example becomes:

```
\documentclass[11pt,b5paper]{book}
\usepackage[tight]{shorttoc}

\begin{document}

\let\tocbreak=\relax
\shorttoc{\centerline{\large{SOMMAIRE}}}{0}

\chapter{Chapter} \section{Section} \section{Another section} \section{Yet another section}
\chapter{Chapter} \section{Section} \section{Another section} \section{Yet another section}
\chapter{Chapter} \section{Section} \section{Another section} \section{Yet another section}
\chapter{Chapter} \section{Section} \section{Another section} \section{Yet another section}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\tocbreak}
\chapter{Chapter} \section{Section} \section{Another section} \section{Yet another section}
\chapter{Last Chapter} 

\let\tocbreak=\pagebreak
\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```